# Karate contains only shortcut fails in v1.4.1

Tags: karate

According to Karate documentation for contains short-cuts The following match arguments should work and do the same:

```
 * def cat = 
  """
  {
    name: 'Billie',
    kittens: [
      { id: 23, name: 'Bob', bla: [{ b: '1'}] },
      { id: 42, name: 'Wild' }
    ]
  }
  """
# this will pass and would be my expectation
* def expected = [{ id: 42, name: 'Wild' }, { id: 23, name: 'Bob', bla: [{ b: '1'}]}]
* match cat == { name: 'Billie', kittens: '#(^^expected)' }

# this also pass but i would assume, that it does not pass
* def expected = [{ id: 42, name: 'Wild' }, { id: 23, name: 'Bob', bla: { b: '1'} }]
* match cat == { name: 'Billie', kittens: '#(^^expected)' }
```

The second one should fail, because the expectation for the parameter "bla" is an object and not an array with an object in it.

I'm using Karate v1.4.1. The same scenario does work as i would assume with v1.2.0.

Comment: yes this may be a bug. feel free to raise an issue. ideally please consider submitting a PR also, you can use this as a reference: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/issues/2170